# Getting error "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest" when using Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've started making a web app using Firebase, and I've finished the code and left the sign in/ log out methods at the end. The sign up works perfectly! It creates the user inside Firebase, but when I try to sign in with the user I've created, there is a table after logging in, but when I sign in with chrome the table is empty and it shows the error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

it works perfectly on Firefox, but not on chrome.

when I check the "network" tab and then refresh under XHR on chrome it shows this:

`getAccountInfo?key=uid` -- where is uid is the ID that firebase provide

inside it it says:

```
[{localId: "uid", email: "my email", emailVerified: false,...}]
```

Sorry if I did something wrong am still new, thank you.

Comment: That warning is harmless. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467144/firebase-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-deprecated. Aside from that, it'll be hard to help without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).